# My C program is crashing when I call a method from a class instance here is the code

Tags: c++, crash

here is the class that I am using.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
class EnDe{

    private:
        int *k;
        char *temp;

    public:

        char * EncryptString(char *str);                         
        char * DecryptString(char *str);       
         EnDe(int *key);};
 EnDe::EnDe(int *key){

    k=key;
}

char * EnDe::EncryptString(char *str){

    int t=2;
    t=(int)k[1]*(int)2;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        temp[i]=str[i]+k[0]-k[2]+2-k[1]+k[3]+t;     


    }
    char alp=k[0]*57;
    for (int y=strlen(str);y<strlen(str)+9;y++){    //--*
        temp[y]=alp+y;                  //--*
    }
    temp[(strlen(str)+9)]='\0';     //--*
    return temp;

}

char * EnDe::DecryptString(char *str){

    int t=2;
    t=k[1]*2;

    for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){

        temp[i]=str[i]-t-k[3]+k[1]-2+k[2]-k[0];  

    }

        temp[(strlen(str)-9)]='\0';
    return temp;

}
```

And here is the main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "EnDe.h"

int main(void){

    char *enc;

    char op;

    printf("\nE to encrypt and D to decrypt");

    int opi[4]={1,2,9,1};   

    EnDe en(opi);

    strcpy(enc,en.EncryptString("It is C's Lounge!! "));

    printf("Encrypted :  %s",enc);

    return 0;
}
```

Something is wrong with en.EncryptString function

when I run the program it stops working giving error and on removing strcpy(enc,en.EncryptString("It is C's Lounge!! ")); it runs. I want this problem to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char *enc;
    strcpy(enc,en.EncryptString("It is C's Lounge!! "));
```

You don't provide any space for the copy - enc doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: so what should I have to do to run the program correctly as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate any memory.

When you say

```
char *foo;
```

You tell the compiler that you want to store a memory address to some data somewhere, but *not* that you also want to store some data. Your class stores two pointers (`int *k` and `char *temp`) that never get any memory assigned to them, and so does your main function with `char *enc`. This can never work.

In C and C++, there are two modes of memory allocation: one is *stack-based* allocation, where you declare variable names in a function, and the compiler or the runtime will automatically allocate and release memory for you; the other is *heap-based* allocation, where you use `malloc` or `new` to allocate memory at run time, and must *manually* release that memory again with `delete` or `free`.

A pointer is "just" a stack-allocated variable that contains the *address* of another memory location. If you don't assign any value to a pointer, it points to invalid memory, and whatever you try to do with it will fail. To fix your program, you must make sure that every pointer points to valid memory. If you want it to point to a stack-based variable, you use the address-of operator:

```
int val = 4;
int *pointer_to_val = &val;
/* the pointer_to_val variable now holds the address of the val variable */
```

If you don't want it to point to a stack-allocated variable, you must allocate the memory yourself.

In C++, heap memory is allocated with the `new` operator, like so:

```
ClassType *instance = new ClassType(arg1, arg2)
```

where `ClassType` is the type of the class you're creating an instance of, `instance` is the pointer where you want to store the address of the instance you've just created, and `arg1` and `arg2` are arguments to the `ClassType` constructor that you want to run.

When you no longer need the allocated memory, you use `delete` to release the memory:

```
delete instance;
```

Alternatively, you can also use the C-style `malloc` and `free` functions. These are not operators; they are functions which return the address of the allocated memory. They do not work for C++ class instances (since you do not run the constructor over the returned memory), but if you want to run a pure-C program, they're all you have. With malloc, you do as follows:

```
char* string = malloc(size);
```

where `string` is the pointer for which you want to allocate memory, and `size` is the number of bytes you want the system to allocate for you. Once you're ready using the memory, you release it with free:

```
free(string);
```

When calling `delete` or `free`, it is not necessary to specify the size of the object (the system remembers that for you). Note, however, that you must make sure to *always* use `delete` for memory allocated with `new`, and to *always* use `free` for memory allocated with `malloc`. Mixing the two will result in undefined behaviour and possibly a crash.